# Date add GMT to hour

Tags: android, date, kotlin, gmt, localdate

```
val startHour = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(pickup.begin())
```

The pickup.begin value is "*Wed Apr 10 10:00:00 GMT+03:00 2019*", so I need the start hour to be 10:00 +3h -> 13:00, but I get startHour value of 10:00.

I don't know how to add the GMT value to hour.

Comment: What is the type of `pickup` ?

Comment: Sorry, what is the type returned by `pickup.begin()` * ?

Comment: `final @Nullable Object begin;

/**
     * The datetime the range begins.
     */
    public @Nullable Object begin() {
      return this.begin;
    }`

.
it is from a generated class

Comment: you need to convert it to your local time

Comment: I need to show the hour from server + GMT  from the response (in that case +3,but it may vary)

Comment: @ArthurAttout I've looked now in debug, the `pickup.begin()` returns a `Date` object

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you’ve misunderstood. `Wed Apr 10 10:00:00 GMT+03:00 2019` is (the textual representation of) a `java.util.Date` the value of which equals 2019-04-10T07:00 UTC. It seems your default time zone is GMT+03:00, and `Date` is trying to be friendly to you and print the time in this time zone, which is why it prints 10:00:00. 13:00 would certainly be incorrect no matter if you wanted the time in UTC or in your own default time zone.

The `Date` class returned from `pickup.begin()` is poorly designed and long outdated, so you may want to consider if a type from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, could be returned instead. It may also make the matter clearer.

Alternatively, convert that `java.util.Date` object to its modern counterpart, a `java.time.Instant`. Look for new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = pickup.begin().toInstant() ;  // Converting legacy `Date` object to modern `Instant` object.
```

Search Stack Overflow and read the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) to learn more about `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime` classes.

You can use java.time on older Android versions if you add ThreeTenABP to your Android project. It’s the Android adaptation of the backport of java.time.

**Links**

- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Locale to your simpledateformat, matching the +3 timezone.

```
val startHour = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.Germany).format(pickup.begin())
```

Comment: It will not make any difference. Locale and time zone are independent concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

I take 'date' as string here

```
  String date="something" 
 val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
 sdf.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
 val gmt = sdf.parse(date)
```

If this is your case

```
Date date="somevalue"
```

then

val gmt = sdf.format(date)

gmt will return you your local time

Comment: well, this adds my GMT which is +2 and not the GMT response from server which is +3

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.